# Preloading and changing images with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm trying to make some basic image slider as a part of JS excersises, and I've noticed something weird when I ran this script.

The source of an image stored in array under the 0 index is changing when I'm trying to change source image in html code with 'setAttribute' method, so when I want to get back from fifth image to one, this proto-slider (nothing is sliding at the moment) is stuck at second image.

My files are named 0.jpg - 5.jpg.

I've preloaded the images to be displayed smoothly without flicker and I'm displaying one image after the page loads, and then I'm trying to change source of this image to source of next image in array of images. Is this the right way to do it?

Here's the code:

```
var images = new Array(5);
var i=0;
function addImages(){
       for (var j=0;j<images.length;j++){
        images[j] = new Image();
        images[j].src = j+".jpg";
        console.log(images[j].src);
    }
    var article = document.getElementById("article");
    article.insertBefore(images[0], document.getElementById("nav"));
}
function next(){
    if (i<images.length-1){
        document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].setAttribute('src',images[++i].src);
        console.log(images[0].src);
}}
function prev(){
if (i>0){
        document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].setAttribute('src', images[--i].src);
        console.log(images[0].src);
    }
}
```

What is the best way to do such a this as dynamically changing image sources?
I've thought about this:

```
    article.removeChild(document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]);
    article.insertBefore(images[++i], document.getElementById("nav"));
```

I want to know if this isn't considered as a bad practice and what are the other ways to do it in single line of code.

Thanks in advance and sorry for grammar mistakes.

Comment: If you want code reviewed, there's [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just insert empty image

```
<img id="someid">
```

and then use `document.getElementById("someid").src=images[0].src`
If you'd like to be sure that images[0] is completely loaded, use onload function, like:

```
images[0].onload=function()
{
    document.getElementById("someid").src=images[0].src;
}
```